# Define $A_{m,n} = \{ x \in Z : n^2x^3+2020x^2+mx=0 \}$ Then the number of pairs (m,n) for which $A_{m,n}$ has exactly two points

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, quadratics

Let m and n be non zero integers. Define $A_{m,n} = \{ x \in R : n^2x^3+2020x^2+mx=0 \}$ Then the number of pairs (m,n) for which $A_{m,n}$ has exactly two points is

(A) 0

(B) 10

(C) 16

(D) $\infty$

My approach is one of the root is x=0 and the quadratic eqn $n^2x^2+2020x+m=0$ must have equal roots.

Condition we get is $n^2m=(101)^2(2)^2(5)^2$. We can choose n^2 4+3C2+1 ways So total no of (m,n) should be 16. Please verify if the solution is correct

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: @I1mbo Thank you

Comment: Just asking, why were you unsure of your answer? Especially if it also matched one of the options

Comment: I got the same answer that you did.  Also, my reasoning agrees with yours up until *near* the end.  **However**, I'm not able to re-produce analysis that would compute # of ways as $2 \times [4 + \binom{3}{2} + 1].$  I'm not saying that your approach is invalid, but simply that I can't figure out how to verify its validity.  My approach would be that in consideration of the product $[(p_1)^2 (p_2)^2 (p_3)^2]$, there are $2^3 = 8$ possibilities re each of $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ may or may not be a factor of $n$.  Then, since $n$ may be positive or negative, the final computation is $(8 \times 2).$